# Is synchronous network communication possible on C

Tags: c

I am fairly new to networking concepts in C, and was wondering about following.

Say I have client and server.

On the client side, I have such code:

```
   1. send(connfd, var1, var1Size);

   2. read(connfd, &x, size1);

   3. close(connfd);
```

The server also does **one** receive and **one** send, e.g.,

```
   1. read(connfd, &var, size);

   2. send(connfd, var1, varSize);
```

My question is following.
On the client side, after the client does `send` -- it takes some time
before the data arrives at server, before server reads it, and sends back
right?

So could not it happen that after client code runs `send`, then
it directly jumps to `read`, but by this time, the server has
not yet managed to prepare response and send it back --
so the read call on the client side (line 2), will receive nothing.
And connection will terminate right? (program will exit).

Is it how it may happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with C, it's about how networking protocols and I/O work.

The answer is that unless you go out of your way to make the I/O *non-blocking*, the `send()` and `recv()` calls are synchronous, i.e. they will *block* if necessary, to wait for available outgoing bandwidth or incoming data.

So the case you describe will typically not happen, the connection will not terminate.

Comment: So in C, recv and send are blocking you mean? (aka synchronous)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I edited to make this even more explicit.

Comment: Just noticed I used `read` and `write` instead of send/recv. Are read and write also blocking?

Comment: Yes, they are. As I wrote, you must explicitly set the socket itself to non-blocking.

Comment: Another important point is that `recv` doesn't wait until the whole buffer is filled. It returns as soon as some data was received which could theoretically be only a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

Both `send` and `read` are **blocking**, meaning that the call will **block** until the command is finished.

- For `send` this means that the call will not finish until the program has send the data (this not necessarily means that the data has arrived, but that the data was passed to a buffer (OS-handled) (depends on the protocol)).
- for `receive` this means that the call will block until there is some data to receive.

So the client, after sending will block in the `receive` call until the server sends a response. And the server will block in the `read` call until the client sends the data. The only malfunction here is if the client calls `send` before the server is started listening on the socket.

Comment: yes, that was basically my question: so you say by default send and receive in C are blocking? e.g., receive waits until some data is received? (I think this is called also synchronous communication)

Comment: yes, they are blocking and this is called synchronous

Comment: Non-blocking APIs exist, and are very useful. But they're much more difficult to reason about, which is why the "ordinary" APIs block.